# Why EF6 LINQ does not generate proper "is null" SQL for null string variable comparison?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

We have an EDMX-based EF6 application, where we'd like to run a LINQ query like this.

```
string category = ... // comes from somewhere and equals to null
context.Product.Where(e => e.Category == category).ToArray();
```

The problem I see is that the generated SQL contains a `[table].[Category] = @p...` in the where clause, regardless of the variable `category` being `null` or not. So at the end of the day the query returns no results if the variable is `null`, instead of generating a proper `is null` criteria and return the proper rows.

I've tested with the explicit `e => e.Category == null` expression and that does generate the `is null` as expected.

I've also checked the EDMX and the SQL, and the corresponding `Category` column is nullable indeed in both places, so that might not be the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is thre any reason you do not do the null check on the LINQ side? I mean, it is not like you can only have one WHERE statement. You do know you can chain them, also dynamically? My standard is basically to do the null check then only add the where clause when t is not null. Otherwise this DOES Look like a bug - open tickets on the github side. At minimum they should generate IS NULL.

Comment: The expectation is wrong, would violate SQL's three-valued logic, and actually *surprise* developers that expected a null value to return nothing. As you posted, EF (and most ORMs) generate parameterized queries. The queries don't change each time a *value* changes.

Comment: `Category = @p1` is very different from `Category = @p1 or Category IS NULL` too, resulting in very different execution plans and performance. EF (or any ORM) can't arbitrarily choose the wider query over the narrower one, as it would return *un*expected results and result in far worse performance. You could argue there should be a switch for people that expect an ORM to *not* use SQL semantics, but that would result in a maintenance nightmare when *other* developers try to understand why a query doesn't behave as expected

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for the clarification, it makes sense. However all I've expected is EF to be *clever*, so that it would notice when parsing my LINQ expression that the expression `category` is basically `null` so it should generate a `[Category] is null` where clause this case. It seems like EF does not evaluate such expressions locally but just generate a parameterized query.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási I would expect EF (or *any* ORM) to *not* violate SQL's behavior. You're asking for EF to use C#'s NULL logic instead of SQL's, even though it's clearly querying a SQL database.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't quite get this point, why would evaluating an expression locally and generate the query accordingly violate any kinds of SQL behavior? IMO it's just about how *smart* the EF LINQ provider is. To me it sounds like a design decision of the LINQ provider.

Comment: Oh I see, didn't catch your updated comment in time. I personally think that the two `null` semantics could be aligned as both mean something like 'not provided'. By the way I got a hint from my college to use the `context.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics` switch. If that is `false`, then I get my expected behavior :)

Comment: @ZoltánTamási the decision is actually very sensible. If `e.Category==category` generates `e.Category=@p1 or e.Category IS NULL`, what would `e.Category==otherEntity.SomeOtherField` do? You'd get conflicting behavior for the same expression, or behavior that violates programmer expectations

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos When `context.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics` is `false` (I guess this is the default), then the generated query is `[Category] = @p OR ([Category] IS NULL AND @p IS NULL)` which IMO is the correct statement in this case, still being parameterized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set `context.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics` to `false`. This is the property which affects the mentioned behavior.

See the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.usedatabasenullsemantics?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)